# Understanding a part of JRip rule-based classifier output

Tags: weka

I've run JRip and i got a set of rules in this form:

```
                                                                      |
                                                                      V
(something >= 0.076) and (someotherthing >= 0.013) => class=1 (944.0/42.0)
```

I'm tring to understand what the numbers 944.0 and 42.0 mean.
Almost sure 944.0 is the number of instances covered by the rule, but I can't really undestand the second one.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the 2nd number is ***number of instances misclassified by rule***

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: sorry, but I believe that it is the answer.

Comment: @GabrielMongeon: please let makak know why you think it would not be an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @makak, I've must have misread your answer. I did not read the parenthesis as a formula but rather a poorly formated answer. It's look like it was choosen as the answer by flagg19, so I guess I was wrong on this one.

Answer (score 0):

The result (A/B) indicates:

- `A`: the weight of all instances supported by the rule
- `B`: the weight of all instances misclassified
- `(A - B)`: the weight of all instances correctly classified, thus `A > B`

Note that, if you are not using weights, each instance has weight 1, and the value represents the number of instances.